# SQL Server Union of geography feature returns FULLGLOBE result

Tags: sql-server, union, asp.net

I have some trouble with SQL Server 2012.

I store coordinates of French cities in my database as geography object (with ESRI 4326) and i want to make the UNION of some cities.

I have in result (with the method `AsTEXT()` ) :

- If I ask for 100 cities : FULLGLOBE
- If I ask for 1 cities : I have the good coordinates

There is a limit of how many cities I can union ?

(I do my sql request in c# with ASP .NET MVC 4 :

```
DbGeography result = System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography.PointFromText("POINT EMPTY", 4326);

//PolygonFromText("POLYGON((0 0,0 1,1 0, 0 0))", 4326);;    
string resultString = "";

try
{
  var commune = db.Communes
    .Where(com => com.IDCommune.StartsWith("073"))
    .Select(com => com);

  foreach(var com in commune)
  {
    if (com.coordinates == null)
    {

    }
    else
    {                       
      result = result.Union(com.coordinates);
    }                   
  }
```

---

I solved my problem. I put my polygon in geometry type and not in geography type and it works.

Answer (score -1):

*This isn't an answer, but it won't fit in a comment*

I'm not sure `STUnion` is the correct tool for what you're hoping to achieve, especially since the union of several points is just another list of the points.  See the example below:

```
DECLARE @p1 geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(1 1)', 4326);
DECLARE @p2 geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-1 -1)', 4326);
SELECT @p1.STUnion(@p2).ToString(); 

// Output: MULTIPOINT ((1 1), (-1 -1))
```

Is the end result supposed to be a bounding box of all the points?  If so, there are other ways to go about this.